# How to make four combination of points with the same ID in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape2, melt, mutate

I am currently trying to make squares (polygons) from a data frame in R and in order to do that (according this [guide](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332427/converting-points-to-polygons-by-group?newreg=e24345e56761422fa3e359ed6a1485fa)), I need to have a data frame with 4 sets of paired points as their lon-lat coordinates.

Using this example:

```
sample_df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2),
                        t = c('2020-01-01','2020-01-01'),
                        intensity = c(1.3,0.6),
                        x1 = c(113.75,114.00),
                        x2 = c(114.00,114.25),
                        y1 = c(8.75,8.75),
                        y2 = c(9.00,9.00))
```

| id | t | intensity | x1 | x2 | y1 | y2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1.3 | 113.75 | 114.00 | 8.75 | 9.00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 0.6 | 114.00 | 114.25 | 8.75 | 9.00 |

What I would like to achieve is to create a data frame that retains the `t` and the `intensity` columns distributed to the `id` column multiplied into 4 pairs of `x1 paired to y1`, `x2 paired to y1`, `x2 paired to y2`, and `x1 paired to y2` values as `lon` and `lat` columns.

The expected output would be a data frame looking something like this:

| id | t | intensity | lon | lat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1.3 | 113.75 | 8.75 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1.3 | 114.00 | 8.75 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1.3 | 114.00 | 9.00 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1.3 | 113.75 | 9.00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 0.6 | 114.00 | 8.75 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 0.6 | 114.25 | 8.75 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 0.6 | 114.25 | 9.00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 0.6 | 114.00 | 9.00 |

I am currently stuck but I am playing around the `mutate()` function of the `dplyr` package, or the `melt()` of `reshape2`.

I would be greatly thankful for your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is 2 reshape/pivots I believe:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
sample_df %>%
    pivot_longer(c("x1","x2"), names_to=NULL, values_to="lon") %>%
    pivot_longer(c("y1","y2"), names_to=NULL, values_to="lat")

## A tibble: 8 × 5
#     id t          intensity   lon   lat
#  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 2020-01-01       1.3  114.  8.75
#2     1 2020-01-01       1.3  114.  9   
#3     1 2020-01-01       1.3  114   8.75
#4     1 2020-01-01       1.3  114   9   
#5     2 2020-01-01       0.6  114   8.75
#6     2 2020-01-01       0.6  114   9   
#7     2 2020-01-01       0.6  114.  8.75
#8     2 2020-01-01       0.6  114.  9
```

The `lon` variable is right - the printing method for *tibbles* is really odd however and shows (`113.75` or `114.25`) and `114.0` as `114.` and `114` respectively.

Comment: The 'erroneous' values in the "lon" column were driving me crazy, I'd assumed I'd done something wrong in my attempts. Your point regarding the _tibbles_ print output is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for this solution @thelatemail, I've tried it in R and it works well with the `sf` package in creating polygons. For my case, the `tibble` displays the 114 and 114. but if turned into a `data.frame1, it well displays 114 and 113.75. Again, thank you

Answer (score -1):

I would `unnest` a `nested` `tibble` (which is generally a phenomenal approach for making combinatorial combinations):

```r
library(tidyr)
x1 = c(113.75,114.00)
x2 = c(114.00,114.25)
y1 = c(8.75,8.75)
y2 = c(9.00,9.00)
tibble(
  id = c(1,2),
  t = c('2020-01-01','2020-01-01'),
  intensity = c(1.3,0.6),
  long = list(c(x1, x2)),
  lat = list(c(y1, y2))
) %>% 
  unnest(c(long, lat))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>      id t          intensity  long   lat
#>   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 2020-01-01       1.3  114.  8.75
#> 2     1 2020-01-01       1.3  114   8.75
#> 3     1 2020-01-01       1.3  114   9   
#> 4     1 2020-01-01       1.3  114.  9   
#> 5     2 2020-01-01       0.6  114.  8.75
#> 6     2 2020-01-01       0.6  114   8.75
#> 7     2 2020-01-01       0.6  114   9   
#> 8     2 2020-01-01       0.6  114.  9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: But the `sample_df` doesn't match your input data?

Comment: @thelatemail That sounds like an XY-problem.

Comment: The `sample_df` is provided in the question. It isn't nested in the example, so I'm not sure how it helps to skip half the manipulation and use a function that wouldn't otherwise work.

Comment: I'm confused, you give me the data, I'll generalize. Again, XY-problem. The problem: how to get combinations of pairs in groups (Y), by pivot/reshape data to get the desired structure (X). Any appropriate `nested` `tibble` can  be made from vectors of the columns.

Comment: @Baraliuh What if OP's data is imported from somewhere else? How can the OP modify his/her original data so that your code can be used directly? It'd better if you can demonstrate how to transform four columns (`x1` to `y2`) into two list-columns (your `long` and `lat`) as the input.